# can i install Visual studio 2003 after installing VS 2005 and VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2003

I have windows XP machine and visual studio 2005 and 2010 are installed on it, which are running fine. 
Some applications are developed with Visual studio .net 2003. So i need to install VS 2003 now.  can i install it on same machine.
Will it impact the VS 2005/10 installations ?

I have referred
[Do I need to uninstall all higher versions of Visual Studio just to reinstall VS 2003 successfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920960/do-i-need-to-uninstall-all-higher-versions-of-visual-studio-just-to-reinstall-vs) 
and
 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robcaron/archive/2005/04/20/410224.aspx?Redirected=true 
but i am not clear whether to go ahead with installation or not.
Please suggest

Comment: The only suggestion that I feel to give is to upgrade your projects as soon as possible.

Comment: @Steve ..you are right. we are upgrading the projects, however till that time we need VS 2003